# Magento getting An error has occured while syncronizing media storages. when I try synchronize media to database

Tags: magento

Seeing this error in exceptions.log

```
> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'INSERT INTO
>    `core_directory_storage` (`name`, `path`, `upload_time`,
>    `parent_id`) VALUES (?, ?, '2015-06-15 09:25:48', ?)
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>    'O-1395' for key 'UNQ_CORE_DIRECTORY_STORAGE_NAME_PARENT_ID'' in
>    /srv/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

I have truncated both core_storage_directory and core_storage_files but it seems to keep having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from the great support team at Anchor Hosting!

We've seen similar issues before.
This appears to be caused by two directories with the same name, but different case.

eg. if the following directories appear under your media somewhere

mydir
myDir

The sync script inserts "mydir" then attempts to insert "myDir" and
thinks it already exists so raises the Integrity constraint violation
as it compares the names disregarding the case.

To avoid this, there are two options:

1. Remove/merge files and directories with the same names but different case.
   or
2. Modify the database schema to use the BINARY attribute for the `name` and `path` on both core_file_storage and core_directory_storage. This will force MySQL to compare in a case-sensitive manner.